# Check if a model already has a FK

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I have the following models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
   id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.id

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

When I try to add a new User, I need to know that the device that is going to be added to that User is not already in use.

How I can check if that device has already an User with it's FK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it with reverse relation `user_set`:

```
device.user_set.exists()
```

Answer (score 2):

If each device can only be linked to one user, then it looks like your model is the wrong way around. I would move the foreign key to the `Device` model.

```
class Device(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey('User', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.id
```

If each user can only have one device as well, then a one-to-one field would be a better choice. You could put this on either model.

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

If you get the relations correct in your models, then you should end up having to write less validation code.